# Streak counter with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

So I'm making this game where there's two boxes and you have to click one of them. If you click the right one you win and the wrong one you lose. I need to make a streak counter that goes up by one every time the player clicks on the winning box and returns to zero if the player loses.

The HTML

```
<div id="result"></div>
<hr/>
<div id="container" style="width:100%">
  <button id="button1" class="but">1</button>
  <button id="button2" class="but">2</button>
</div>
<button type="button" id="start">RANDOMIZE</button>
```

The Javascript

```
 <script>

  function getRandomItemNum(length) {
  return Math.ceil(Math.random() * length)
}

function recalculateWinItem() {
  winItem = getRandomItemNum(array.length);
}

function checkIsWin(buttonNum) {
  var text = `Clicked <b>${buttonNum}</b>. Win item: ${winItem};  `
  text += buttonNum === winItem ? "You won" : "You lose";
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = text;
}
var array = [...document.querySelectorAll("#container .but")].map(function(but) { 
  but.addEventListener("click",function() { checkIsWin(+this.id.replace("button",""))})
  return `(${but.id})`
});
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  document.getElementById("start").addEventListener("click", recalculateWinItem)
  recalculateWinItem();
})

   </script>
```

I thought this would be easy but I just can't wrap my head around it.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add a variable `score`, and increment its value if the user won, otherwise reset it to zero. I changed your ternary operation `text += buttonNum === winItem ? "You won" : "You lose";` to a standard if/else block to make it simpler:

```js
var score = 0;
  function getRandomItemNum(length) {
  return Math.ceil(Math.random() * length)
}

function recalculateWinItem() {
  winItem = getRandomItemNum(array.length);
}

function checkIsWin(buttonNum) {
  var text = `Clicked <b>${buttonNum}</b>. Win item: ${winItem};  `
  if(buttonNum === winItem) {
    text += "You won";
    score++; //increment score
    console.log(score);
  }
  else {
    text += "You lose";
    score = 0; //reset score to zero
    console.log(score);
  }
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = text;
}
var array = [...document.querySelectorAll("#container .but")].map(function(but) { 
  but.addEventListener("click",function() { checkIsWin(+this.id.replace("button",""))})
  return `(${but.id})`
});
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  document.getElementById("start").addEventListener("click", recalculateWinItem)
  recalculateWinItem();
})
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
<hr/>
<div id="container" style="width:100%">
  <button id="button1" class="but">1</button>
  <button id="button2" class="but">2</button>
</div>
<button type="button" id="start">RANDOMIZE</button>
```

Comment: It works but it doesn't show it to the counter to the player.

Comment: @Elguti Well, you could replace the console.log by some innerHTML altering, right?

Comment: Or use `text += " Score: " + score;` if you want the score to show next to the other info you're displaying.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var winStreak = 0;

function getRandomItemNum(length) {
  return Math.ceil(Math.random() * length)
}

function recalculateWinItem() {
  winItem = getRandomItemNum(array.length);
}

function checkIsWin(buttonNum) {
  var text = `Clicked <b>${buttonNum}</b>. Win item: ${winItem};  `
  if(buttonNum === winItem){
    text += "You won"
    document.getElementById("winstreak").innerText = 'Streak counter: ' + (++winStreak)
  } else {
    document.getElementById("winstreak").innerText = 'Streak counter: 0';
    winStreak = 0;
    text += "You lose";
  }
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = text;
}
var array = [...document.querySelectorAll("#container .but")].map(function(but) { 
  but.addEventListener("click",function() { 
    checkIsWin(+this.id.replace("button",""))
  })
  return `(${but.id})`
});
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  document.getElementById("start").addEventListener("click", recalculateWinItem)
  recalculateWinItem();
})
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
<hr/>
<div id="winstreak"></div>
<div id="container" style="width:100%">
  <button id="button1" class="but">1</button>
  <button id="button2" class="but">2</button>
</div>
<button type="button" id="start">RANDOMIZE</button>
```